# Authentication with Google or Facebook

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and I want to authenticate users with their Google or Facebook account

Comment: Any code? Attempt? Anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Url http://codechallenger.blogspot.com/2011/03/autenticacion-de-usuarios-contra.html

The post is in spanish

Comment: Great post! by the way, the post might be in Spanish but the code is all English!

Answer (score 0):

I believe both of those providers support OpenID. While some people out there bash it, I know other sites that have used it with great success.

I would start by finding a good OpenID provider for .NET and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend your first step would be to look into authenticating using OpenID (and integrating with WIF) as both Google and Facebook provide OpenID