# Gmail credentials for Authentication of ASP.net Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, gmail

I have two textboxes for username and password now i want users to enter their company email Id and password (Username and password is powered by google ,webserver is google) and log in to the ASP.net website.Create session of username and password .Futher i want the user to able to send the email from asp.net website using same gmail credential.Thank you in advance and any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435322/authentication-with-google-or-facebook

Comment: You described what your code should do but you didn't ask a question. What have you tried and what trouble have you encountered?

Comment: Please do not actually request their google account's username and password.  Any programmer that does this shouldn't be allowed near a computer.

Comment: @ M.Babcock my question is how to do it is it possible.@ Ramhound : sorry but my intension were not like that i misinterpreted myself...i want something like janrain.com  can this possible please help me out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer which i wanted is this and this code works fine.and I am not storing password anywhere in the session and database.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
      <div id="loginform">  
        <div id="NotLoggedIn" runat="server">  
          Log in with <img src="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" />  
            <asp:Button ID="btnLoginToGoogle" Runat="server" Text="Google"     OnCommand="OpenLogin_Click"  
              CommandArgument="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" />  
          <p /><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAlertMsg" />  
        </div>  
      </div>  
    </form>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenIdAjaxRelyingParty rp = new OpenIdAjaxRelyingParty();
        var r = rp.GetResponse();
        if (r != null)
        {
            switch (r.Status)
            {


       case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                NotLoggedIn.Visible = false;
                Session["GoogleIdentifier"] = r.ClaimedIdentifier.ToString();
                Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx");
                break;
            case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                lblAlertMsg.Text = "Cancelled.";
                break;
        }

    }

}
protected void OpenLogin_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string discoveryUri = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
    var b = new UriBuilder(Request.Url) { Query = "" };
    var req = openid.CreateRequest(discoveryUri, b.Uri, b.Uri);
    req.RedirectToProvider();
}
}
```

but i still have further doubt is how to get the username by which the user is logged to create session ...???It can be done i have seen it somewhere...

Comment: The username (email address, rather) will be returned to you after successful login and the redirect from Google. The user will be asked at google.com to authorize your app to even see the email address (only once, after first successful login), and only after that, you'll get the user back and that email address. I don't know technicality of that, though.

Comment: @Hari i still not found the solution to get the email id of user after the sucessful login...???Is it possible to get the email id.?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the OpenId library for C#.

http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/

This will give you a good start. This way, the user won't have to use his password directly and will be redirect to the provider that will grant authentification for your site.

Answer (score 0):

Nah, Google won't let you do that. You'll have to do something similar to what StackOverflow is doing (provide OpenID functionality to authenticate **at** google.com).

Comment: Some thing like http://www.janrain.com/ can do it for me. only will he able to send email from same asp.net application

Comment: I don't think so - I just watched a demo video there, and Google's login page shows in a pop-up. So, while you can certainly cram uid/pwd textboxes on your page claiming that they will login at google, only a fool would actually enter them there w/o checking the url first. So, even if you manage to pull that off, I doubt you'll have many users.

Comment: Answer which i wanted is this

Comment: It was not harsh @Hari . I did not ask question properly.