# Login with gmail account through c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, openid, dotnetopenauth

i am using DotNetOpenID dll for logging my sample application through gmail authentication through c# .net

code which i used was

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenIdRelyingParty rp = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        var r = rp.GetResponse();
        if (r != null)
        {            
            switch (r.Status)
            {
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                    NotLoggedIn.Visible = false;
                    Session["GoogleIdentifier"] = r.ClaimedIdentifier.ToString();
                    Response.Redirect("About.aspx"); //redirect to main page of your website  
                    break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                    lblAlertMsg.Text = "Cancelled.";
                    break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                    lblAlertMsg.Text = "Login Failed.";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OpenLogin_Click(object src, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string discoveryUri = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        var b = new UriBuilder(Request.Url) { Query = "" };
        var req = openid.CreateRequest(discoveryUri, b.Uri, b.Uri);
        req.RedirectToProvider();
    }
```

it works well when i click the gmail login button it goes to the gmail page and authenticate as i need.

but my problem is  **AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated status was failed** after authentication always even though i am giving correct username and password of gmail account

Waiting for valuable response and comments

Answer (score 3):

As par your requirement.You should try this code or see this link :
[Gmail credentials for Authentication of ASP.net Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199958/gmail-credentials-for-authentication-of-asp-net-website)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenIdAjaxRelyingParty rp = new OpenIdAjaxRelyingParty();
    var response = rp.GetResponse();
    if (response != null)
    {
        switch (response.Status)
        {
            case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                NotLoggedIn.Visible = false;
                Session["GoogleIdentifier"] = response.ClaimedIdentifier.ToString();

                var fetchResponse = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
                Session["FetchResponse"] = fetchResponse;
                var response2 = Session["FetchResponse"] as FetchResponse;

                string UserName = response2.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First) ?? "Guest"; // with the OpenID Claimed Identifier as their username.
                string UserEmail = response2.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email) ?? "Guest";   

                Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx");
                break;

            case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                lblAlertMsg.Text = "Cancelled.";
                break;
        }

    }
}
protected void OpenLogin_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{

    string discoveryUri = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();

    var url = new UriBuilder(Request.Url) { Query = "" };
    var request = openid.CreateRequest(discoveryUri); // This is where you would add any OpenID extensions you wanted
    var fetchRequest = new FetchRequest(); // to fetch additional data fields from the OpenID Provider

    fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
    fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First);
    fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);
    fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.HomeAddress.Country);
    request.AddExtension(fetchRequest);

    request.RedirectToProvider();

}
```

Comment: is there any way to logout once we successfully Authenticated in OpenId. Please Help..?

Comment: see these link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530457/logout-with-gmail-account-through-c-sharp-net

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with DotNetOpenID dll.  However, I would recommend using Fiddler to do a capture of the data in the POST that is being sent during login and ensure that you are sending the correct content in your post.  C# provides `HttpWebRequest` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and `HttpWebResponse` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) in `System.Net`.  Is there any reason you aren't using the these from the System.dll instead?

Make sure that when you get your cookies back from your POST that you put them in your cookie collection for any subsequent request.

There is a nice sample class to handle requests in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892042/create-http-post-request-and-receive-response-using-c-sharp-console-application/3892075#3892075) answered by cement